# Overusing CDATA in XML?

Tags: xml, cdata

I'm integrating with a national postal carrier that uses XML to specify a shipment manifest (mail items being sent on a given day).
The specification requests that every element in the address be contained in a CDATA section.
Why is this being done?  Can't regular XML escaping account for text in an address?

For example:

```
   <RecipientInfo>
      <RecipientName><![CDATA[Michael Ong]]></RecipientName>
      <RecipientAddress1><![CDATA[test address 1]]></RecipientAddress1>
  <RecipientAddress2><![CDATA[test address 2]]></RecipientAddress2>
      <RecipientPostalCode><![CDATA[21533]]></RecipientPostalCode>
      <RecipientContactNumber><![CDATA[96600000001]]></RecipientContactNumber>
   </RecipientInfo>
   <SenderInfo>
     <SenderName><![CDATA[Sally Ng]]></SenderName>
     <SenderAddress1><![CDATA[sender address 1]]></SenderAddress1>
     <SenderPostalCode><![CDATA[518000]]></SenderPostalCode>
   </SenderInfo>
```

Comment: "Why is this being done?" — Ask the person who wrote the code which generates the XML. We can't read their mind.

Comment: "Can't regular XML escaping account for text in an address?" — There is no situation where you can use CDATA that you can't use escaping (and none of the data in your example needs either).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is this being done? Can't regular XML escaping account for text in an address?

It's being done because someone didn't want to deal with problems down the road when some character or other wasn't escaped properly. CDATA makes the problems go away.

There was probably a design team somewhere who pulled a sample off the internet and it used CDATA, so now it's yours. 8-)

> I'm integrating with a national postal carrier

You're not going to change anybody's mind. The best you'll do is make people angry.

Just do what they want and get on with your life.